# Where did Ravan go after his death by lord Ram?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

As ravan was killed by lord Ram, so he should go to heaven. I also read from some post Ravan took rebirth as another Rakhasa and killed by lord Krishna in Mahabharat.

Why did Ravan not go to heaven? Where did he go after his death?

If Ravan got rebirth, what is the story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ravana was not liberated or didn't go to heaven after being killed by Śrī Rāma. He was born again as Śiśupāla in the 28<sup>th</sup> Dwapara Yuga.

Ravana was rebirth of one of the gatekeepers of Vaikunta. He was the Rebirth of Jaya. Vijaya was born as Kumbhakarna.

This was due to curse of Sanat Kumaras given to Jaya and Vijaya. According to that curse, they are born as Rakshasas for three lives.

> The Lord replied: O brāhmaṇas, know that the punishment you inflicted on them was originally ordained by Me, and therefore they will fall to a birth in a demoniac family. But they will be firmly united with Me in thought through mental concentration intensified by anger, and they will return to My presence shortly. [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 3.6.26](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/16/26).

They were separated from the Lord for three births.

> > While Jaya and Vijaya, thus cursed by the sages, were falling to the material world, they were addressed as follows by the same sages, who were very kind to them. “O doorkeepers, after three births you will be able to return to your positions in Vaikuṇṭha, for then the duration of the curse will have ended.[Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 7.10.39](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/1/39)

1. The gatekeepers Jaya and Vijaya were born as Hiraṇyākṣa and Hiraṇyakaśipu respectively. Lord Vishnu killed Hiraṇyākṣa in the incarnation of Varāha and Hiraṇyakaśipu by incarnationg as Narasimha.
2. Jaya as Rāvaṇa and Vijaya as Kumbhakarṇa. Both of them were killed by Lord Rāma.
3. Jaya as Śiśupāla and Vijaya as Dantavakra. They were slain by śrī Kṛṣṇa effortlessly.

> Thus the two associates of Lord Viṣṇu who had become Hiraṇyākṣa and Hiraṇyakaśipu, the sons of Diti, were both killed. By illusion they had thought that the Supreme Lord, who is situated in everyone’s heart, was their enemy. Being cursed by the brāhmaṇas, the same two associates took birth again as Kumbhakarṇa and the ten-headed Rāvaṇa. These two Rākṣasas were killed by Lord Rāmacandra’s extraordinary power.  [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 7.10.35-36](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/10/35).
>
> They both took birth again in human society as Śiśupāla and Dantavakra and continued in the same enmity toward the Lord. It is they who merged into the body of the Lord in your presence.  [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 7.10.38](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/10/38).

Rāvaṇa was reborn as Śiśupāla, as the son of Damaghosha, king of Chedi kingdom. Śiśupāla was killed by Lord Kṛṣṇa in the third birth. He was killed during the Rajasuya yaga when he insulted Kṛṣṇa.

The killing of him was explained in detail in [SECTION XLIV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02044.htm) of Sabha Prava the Mahabharata. You can read it there in detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is a story attributed to Jaya and Vijaya, the gatekeepers of Vishnu, from the Srimad Bhagavatam.

> Once the Sanaka sages (the boy-saints who are always in their
>   childhood even though they are the eldest of Brahma’s children – they
>   are four in number Sanaka, Sanatana, Sanandana, Sanatkumara) by their
>   yogic power went to Vaikunta to see Vishnu, the Lord after knowing
>   whom there remains nothing else to be known. They passed through six
>   gates and there were two young people brilliant & shining who were
>   guarding the seventh gate. Since these sages don’t differentiate
>   between anything as they perceive the Self everywhere, they started to
>   enter through the gate. At this the gate keepers stopped them with
>   their staff. These two gate keepers were called Jaya and Vijaya
>   (brothers). The sanaka sages were angry and they cursed that Jaya and
>   Vijaya be born on the earth. They proclaimed that a person will fear
>   another only if he himself is bad. Similarly since they feared lest
>   these saints might disturb or harm Vishnu, they stopped them. Thus
>   their mind also was not pure. And hence they were cursed so as to be
>   born on Earth where the mind is affected by the three characteristics
>   of lust, greed and anger.
>
> Hearing this curse of the saints, Jaya and Vijaya repented for their
>   action. They immediately fell at the feet of the saints and asked
>   pardon for the same. They asked the saints to take back their curse.
>
> At this time, Lord Vishnu himself came down to where they were
>   standing. The sanaka saints were more than satisfied as they could get
>   a glimpse of the Lord. The Lord out of his compassion said to Jaya and
>   Vijaya that it was with his consent that such a curse happened. He
>   explained that once when he was immersed in Samadhi, his wife Lakshmi
>   came to see him. They did not allow her to go in. And because of that,
>   they were cursed by the sanaka sages. But Lord said to them that you
>   will be born in the Earth as demons for three births, worship ME
>   through anger and after that you will return to my abode and be always
>   merged in the ultimate reality of Brahman.

The 3 births were Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakashipu at the start of Treta Yuga, Ravana and Kumbhakarna in mid Treta, and Shishupal and Dantavakra in Dwapara.

Comment: Nice find and good answer. Also try to add some  quotes directly  from scriptures.